# Do i need to connect to database every HTTP request in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, database, node.js

I am using LocomotiveJS(MVC) based on ExpressJS for developing my first simple API.. I am still in learning phase.. I am using mysql as my database..

My question is, do i need to initiate a connection to mysql everytime there's a controller request?

Here's my code :

```
SongsController.show = function() {
//this.title = 'Locomotive';
console.log("nice imbasss");
var contacts = SongsModel.foo("GOOD");

var dbConnection = DBUtilities.connectMysql();
var contactsArr = [];
dbConnection.query('select * from contacts', function(err, rows, fields) {
    //console.log(err);
    console.log(rows);
    //console.log(fields);
    //contactsArr = rows;
});
DBUtilities.endMysql(dbConnection);
};
```

As you can notice, everytime songs/show is called, connectMysql() is called.. Am i doing right?

Comment: You should use a [connection pool](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections).

Answer (score 1):

You should connect MySQL everytime when you fire a query to MySQL and should close your connection after that because mysql injection may occur by third party.